# Printf prints empty string

Tags: c

I am trying to reverse a char, however when I try to print it, it prints nothing.
What am I doing wrong?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
   char str[50] = "geeksforgeeks";
   char *rvsd;
   
   int slen = strlen(str);
   int right = strlen(str);

   for(int i = 0;i<=slen;i++) {
       rvsd[i] = str[right];
       right--;
   }
   

   printf("%s", rvsd);
   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A pointer is exactly what its name implies: It's something that point somewhere else. Now, please tell us where your pointer variable `rvsd` is pointing.

Comment: I changed it, same thing happens

Comment: Now you have to remember that strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** strings*. The null-terminator of the string `str` will be stored at position `str[strlen(str)]`. Now explain your copying loop in great details to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). For example, what is the first character you copy? Where in `rvsd` will it be placed?

Comment: Lastly, please note that the geekforgeeks site is not well-regarded among experienced programmers. It tend to teach bad habits, and sometimes even directly invalid code. It also tend to teach how to solve so-called "competition" or "judge" sites, and what you learn from those are very seldom useful outside of those sites themselves.

Comment: Was it you who just asked a very similar question on this same code, that's now been deleted? I mentioned the lack of nul-termination in a comment on that question

Comment: @PaulHankin I deleted the question because I wanted to add different code and the account got locked because someone negged

Comment: OK, but do you see how it's a waste of peoples' time to ask a question, get feedback, delete it all, and then ask a question which was already answered by feedback on the previous question?

Answer (score 0):

you should put str[right-1], and use normal variable rvsd[50]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
   char str[50] = "geeksforgeeks";
   char rvsd[50];

   int slen = strlen(str);
   int right = strlen(str);

   for(int i = 0;i<=slen;i++) {
       rvsd[i] = str[right-1];
       right--;
   }


   printf("%s", rvsd);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use another vector of the same type to do this exchange of information, a pointer would not help you in this situation, here are a example where you don't need to store the string

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
   char str[50] = "geeksforgeeks";

   int slen = strlen(str);

   for(int i = slen;i>0;i--) {
       printf("%c",str[i-1]);
   }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are no vectors in C. _"a pointer would not help you in this situation"_: a pointer could be used to point into `str` or to point to a dynamic allocation, either of which might be helpful. OP seems intent on _copying_ a reversed string, not just printing it. Note that the second `i--` (or possibly the first for the perverse) is a mistake in your code. Also be aware that `strlen` returns `size_t`, not `int`.

Comment: Another example showing how you can store it using another vector has already been shown by AlCo2